# Does lldb have "info threads" like gdb

Tags: lldb

How to check how many threads run and step in different threads in LLDB? GDB has info threads. Does LLDB have similar commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the:

```
(lldb) help thread
```

command to see what you can do with threads in lldb.

```
(lldb) thread list
```

will list the threads and

```
(lldb) thread select
```

will select the thread you're going to inspect or step. There's an lldb cheat sheet for gdb users here:

http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html

though it looks like it doesn't have `thread list`.

Comment: BTW, if you do `apropos thread` in lldb it will show you all the commands related to threads.